# How to say "I will have arrived home by 6 pm."

Tags: grammar, tense, aspect, particle-まで

I've just started Japanese, so please go easy on the grammar!

I see from this website that ~madeni means "by that time," but I'm not sure if you just append that to the time you want to specify (i.e., rokujimadeni). Also, is there a perfect and/or future perfect tense equivalent in Japanese?

Comment: I came up with ６時には家に着いている when I just read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### ~madeni (~までに)

Yes, as you said, it's that simple - append "~までに" to the time you want to specify.

**But!** Since this is used in future perfect, it's kinda weird to say までに. We say **までには** (madeniwa.)
**には** is a combination of `case particle` に and `engagement particle` は.
**に** indicates the time the action ends (or starts,) and **は** indicates the topic (or important point) in the sentence.

### Perfect / future perfect

There are 3 possible ways to interpret those tenses.

- **Continuation**
- **Experience**
- **Completion**

And of course we have separate translations for those. We use:

- **"~しつづけている"** for continuation

  > (Ex. He's been sick since yesterday - 彼{かれ}は 昨日{きのう}から 病気{びょうき}で寝{ね}**つづけている**)
- **"~したことがある"** for experience

  > (Ex. I've been to Japan in the past - 私{わたし}は 前{まえ}に 日本{にほん}に 行{い}っ**たことがある**
- **"~しまった"** or **"~したところだ"** for completion

  > I've arrived home - 私{わたし}は 家{いえ}に つい**たところだ**

And we use "~だろう" for future patterns, like:

> It'll rain soon. もうすぐ 雨{あめ}が 降{ふ}る **だろう**

However, it's not that simple to combine those, because the translation changes (because it sounds weird)

- For continuation, say "~**したことになるだろう**"

  > I'll have lived in Japan for 5 years next August - 来年{らいねん}の 8月{がつ}で 私は 日本に 5年間{ねんかん} 住{す}んだ ことになるだろう
- For experience, say "~**したことになるだろう**" (same as continuation because I don't think there's *much* difference in situation - in both usage the subject is still doing the thing.)
- For completion, say "~**しているだろう**"

  - Let's take your sentence:

    > I'll have arrived home by 6pm - 私{わたし}は 6時{じ}まで**には** 家{いえ}に 帰{かえ}って**いるだろう**

Comment: I thought that だろう expressed probability. Why do we need it for the sentence "I'll have lived in Japan for 5 years next August"? Unlike the rain example, that seems to be  a certainty, unless  you move or die.

Comment: @user3856370 Yeah, you're right. But that's how I learned in jr. hi- and high school. Maybe だろう is one of *an explicit indication* to show the original sentence was in future pattern. You know, that entrance exam for screening the students looks for such small (and sometimes weird-sounding) differences. They want to mark you as low they can. So you want to *appeal* that you *understand everything they asked* to avoid getting low score. And I think one would get better grade (if any) if they add だろう than forgetting it.

Comment: だろう is probably used because it is not certain that he will complete those 5 years, it is the probability of the future, i.e. by next Aug (if I probably stay there) ill complete 5 years

Answer (score 1):

Grammar wise it requires the attachment "hazu desu" (means should be... plus other connotations), the present continuous verb(te form)+iru ...
read [this page by Maggiesensei](http://maggiesensei.com/2012/11/14/request-lesson-how-and-when-to-use-%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9Ahazu/) for hazu desu.

[page for -teiru](http://maggiesensei.com/2014/07/31/how-to-use-v%EF%BC%8B%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B-teiru-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-teimasu/)

She is awesome in my opinion, and her pages are filled with examples as well as incredible explanations!

My translation would probably be of the english sentence "I should be home from 6pm (onwards <-- Implied)". Which has a similar feel.

> 私は午後6時から家に戻っているはずです。
>
> watashi ha gogo roku-ji kara ie ni modotteiru hazu desu.

gogo just means afternoon, so 18:00 not 06:00. The rest is particles and vocab.

Keep in mind there is no one correct way to say something in language, so this is what I would have strung up. However my grammar may have different connotations so i'd appreciate being pulled up on anything wrong in my understanding!

Comment: If possible, please try to quote or summarize relevant information from pages that you link. This helps if for some reason people are not able to access the webpages.

Comment: Ah! i didn't know this ... In future I will. I hope I got all the relevant information across. Thank you.